# Heroku, resque, unicorn -- '[COBALT] could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer'.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, unicorn

Any idea's whats causing this message in the log?

```
'[COBALT] could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer'.
```

I think it's an issue in one of the before_fork/after_fork procs -- or is is just Heroku issues unrelated to this code?

resque.rb

```
require 'resque/server'

ENV["REDIS_URL"] ||= "redis://localhost:6379/"

uri          = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
$redis       = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
Resque.redis = $redis

Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
```

unicorn.rb

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 20
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')
  end

end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = ENV['REDIS_URL']
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end

end
```